# network packet lengths in python

Tags: python, string, network-programming, hex

I am trying to generate a packet header, which contains the data length.
For example, if the data length is 5, the hex string suppose to be:
'0500'
If it's 100, it suppose to be:
'6400'
if 1050:
'1a40'
And so on.
Is there a nice way to do that in python?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`struct.pack('<H', ...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) to pack the int as a 2-byte unsigned short in a string in little-endian format.  Then use [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) to return the hexadecimal representation of the string:

```
import struct
import binascii

binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<H', 1050))
# '1a04'

binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<H', 100))
# '6400'

binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<H', 5))
# '0500'
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Is there a way to do it if I want something like:
5: '05000000'
100: '64000000'
and with even bigger numbers than unsigned short?

Comment: Use `binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<L', 100))` to pack the int as a 4-byte unsigned long. The hexadecimal representation requires 2 characters for each byte. That's why the 8 characters in `'64000000'` correspond to a *4-byte* unsigned long. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings) for more on the format strings used by `struct.pack`.